# Hiding Tab(s) in MaterialDesign Tabablz TabablzControl

Tags: material-design, tabcontrol, material-design-in-xaml

I would like to bind a TabItem's visibility property to a bool property in my viewmodel  (via converter, true=visible false=collapsed), but the visibility property on the TabItem does not hide the tab. I don't want to hide all of the tab, just individual ones.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to have something similiar. I asked the developer about it, but this is not possible with Dragablz (which is Tabablz). The TabItem itself is not used in dragablz.

A workaround for this could be using materialdesign radiobuttons as tab headers instead of dragablz. Radio buttons can be collapsed.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="4">
   <RadioButton x:Name="FirstTab" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTabRadioButton}" Margin="4" Visibility="Collapsed" IsChecked="True" Content="FIRST" />
   <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTabRadioButton}" Margin="4" IsChecked="False" Content="SECOND" />
   <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTabRadioButton}" Margin="4" IsChecked="False" Content="THIRD" />
</StackPanel>
```

now you just have to create some grids below them, which have their visibility bound to the IsChecked attribute of the corresponding radio button. This way you can show only the grid which is bound to the currently selected radio button. You need a bool2visibility converter, maybe the default one shipped with wpf works (the one in my example is a custom one).

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, Source={x:Reference FirstTab}, Converter={StaticResource Bool2VisibilityConverter}}">
```

Comment: Thanks My app is a collection of image processing tools. Each tool process an input image and creates an output image. Some tools require an editor to select part of an image for processing. I didn't want this editor tab to show if the tool doesn't use one. I worked around the problem by using messages. When the operator selects a tool, I send a message that is received in the view., where I just remove the tabitem from the tabcontrol, if necessary.